# How to close the TcpClient with a timeout?

Tags: c#, .net-core, tcpclient

I'm using .NET Core and want to send messages via TCP. For this I'm using the `TcpClient` class and created a custom service. This solution works for now, not sure if I can improve it

```
class MyTcpService : IMyTcpService
{
    private readonly TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();

    public async Task Send(byte[] bytesToSend)
    {
        if (!tcpClient.Connected) // Check if client was closed before
        {
            await tcpClient.ConnectAsync("127.0.0.1", 5000); // Read values from config
        }

        NetworkStream networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
        
        // Send the message
        await networkStream.WriteAsync(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);

        // Read the response
        byte[] responseBuffer = new byte[1024]; // Read value from config
        int amountOfResponseBytes = await networkStream.ReadAsync(responseBuffer, 0, responseBuffer.Length);
        string responseMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseBuffer, 0, amountOfResponseBytes);

        // Close the connection with a timeout if true
        if (true) // Read value from config
        {
            networkStream.Close(1000); // Read value from config
            tcpClient.Close();
        }

        // Handle the response message here
        // ...
    }
}
```

I want to inject `IMyTcpService` as a transient service. I would like to know how to close the client with a timeout? The `Socket` class has a `Close` method accepting a timeout parameter

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.close?view=netcore-3.1#System_Net_Sockets_Socket_Close_System_Int32_

but I'm not able to find an equivalent for the `TcpClient` just for its `NetworkStream`.

Comment: What do you mean by "close the client with a timeout"? A `TcpClient` is just providing/creating connections. If you want a timeout because sending or receiving data takes too long, that timeout should be handled on the `NetworkStream` in your example

Comment: I found a very old code example using a `Socket` as the TcpClient. And this class has a close method with a timeout (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.close?view=netcore-3.1#System_Net_Sockets_Socket_Close_System_Int32_) so I thought maybe I should do this too

Comment: ReadAsync can take in a CancellationToken. You can set it's timeout through it's CancellationTokenSource. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_Threading_CancellationTokenSource__ctor_System_Int32_)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment you are awaiting both the `WriteAsync` and `ReadAsync` calls. Because of this the timeout in your call to `networkStream.Close(1000)` should have no impact and the connection will always close immediately as no data is waiting to be sent/received. For neither the write or read you have specified a timeout, which means they won't return until data has finished being transferred.

> I would like to know how to close the client with a timeout?

It's not clear why you want this or what you want to achieve with this. [TcpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient?view=netcore-3.1) is simply a wrapper around a [NetworkStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream?view=netcore-3.1) which in turn wraps around a [Socket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket?view=netcore-3.1). So handling timeouts both on the `TcpClient` and the `NetworkStream` doesn't make much sense.

---

**Resource management:**

In your current example I would first of all advise you to keep the `TcpClient` inside the  `Send` method instead of a class field. If you don't need to use the `TcpClient` in other places (which expect you don't since you are closing it in the `Send` function) you should narrow it's scope for easier resource management. While doing that I'd suggest you make use of the [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) to avoid forgetting to properly dispose your resources. This applies to all types that implement the `IDisposable` interface (of course there are exceptions to this).

**Handling timeout:**

To handle timeouts in this snippet of code you have shared I suggest you configure the timeout on the write and read operations rather than the close operation, since your code is very sequential. An example of what that could look like:

```
class MyTcpService : IMyTcpService
{
    public async Task Send(byte[] bytesToSend)
    {
        string responseMessage;
        using (tcpClient = new TcpClient())
        {
            if (shouldUseTimeout) // From config
            {
                tcpClient.ReceiveTimeout = 1000; // From config
                tcpClient.SendTimeout = 1000; // From config
            }
            await tcpClient.ConnectAsync("127.0.0.1", 5000); // Read values from config

            NetworkStream networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
        
            // Send the message
            await networkStream.WriteAsync(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);

            // Read the response
            byte[] responseBuffer = new byte[1024]; // Read value from config
            int amountOfResponseBytes = await networkStream.ReadAsync(responseBuffer, 0, responseBuffer.Length);
            responseMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseBuffer, 0, amountOfResponseBytes);
        }
        // The tcpClient is now properly closed and disposed of

        // Handle the response message here
        // responseMessage...
    }
}
```

---

**Update in response to the comment 13/10/2020:**

> hey, thanks for your reply :) I tried to improve your answer, what do you think about this snippet? pastebin.com/7kTvtTv2

From your https://pastebin.com/7kTvtTv2:

```
public async Task<string> Send(byte[] messageToSend)
{
    string responseMessage;

    using (TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient())
    {
        await tcpClient.ConnectAsync("127.0.0.1", 5000); // From config

        NetworkStream networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
        await networkStream.WriteAsync(messageToSend, 0, messageToSend.Length);
        await networkStream.FlushAsync();
        tcpClient.Client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send); // shutdown gracefully

        byte[] responseBuffer = new byte[256]; // This can be of any size
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        int amountOfResponseBytes;

        do
        {
            amountOfResponseBytes = await networkStream.ReadAsync(responseBuffer, 0, responseBuffer.Length);
            string responseData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseBuffer, 0, amountOfResponseBytes);
            stringBuilder.Append(responseData);
        } while (amountOfResponseBytes > 0);

        responseMessage = stringBuilder.ToString();
    }

    return responseMessage;
}
```

Looks pretty good to me. Only some minor comments:

`await networkStream.FlushAsync()` - it seems like this should be unnecessary when I look at the [remarks for the `Flush` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream.flush?view=netcore-3.1#remarks) but I haven't tested it:

> The Flush method implements the Stream.Flush method; however, because NetworkStream is not buffered, it has no effect on network streams. Calling the Flush method does not throw an exception

`tcpClient.Client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send)` - this method simply tells the `Socket` to no longer allow writing/sending data. Since your `TcpClient` only stays within the `Send` method and therefore not being shared anywhere it seems a little unnecessary too. I think the `Shutdown` method is mostly relevant if you don't have complete control over when the `Socket` is used.

`do { ... } while (...)` - looks good to me. Just remember the `responseBuffer` need to be a multiple of 8 if you are dealing with ASCII characters so you don't end up trying to decode a partial character.

**Where did the timeout handling go?** Did you forget to add timeout handling or is it not relevant anymore? Currently, if you have a lot of data to send or receive or the network is just slow, the `WriteAsync` and `ReadAsync` calls may potentially take a long time.

Comment: hey, thanks for your reply :) I tried to improve your answer, what do you think about this snippet? https://pastebin.com/7kTvtTv2

Comment: @OlafSvenson I added an update to the answer with some comments

Comment: thanks! I don't need the basic timeout handling anymore :) I think this code is fine for now